# Unable to show static image using img tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show some static Images from the Folder using img tag

First tried using

```
<img border="0" src="E:\\liferaytomcat\\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4\\tomcat-7.0.22\\Uploaded Files\\1146Wj.jpeg" alt="Pulpit rock" wid`th="304" height="228" />
```

Also tried with

```
<img border="0" src="/E:/liferaytomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4/tomcat-7.0.22/Uploaded Files/1146Wj.jpeg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228" />
```

Also tried with

```
<img border="0" src="E:\liferaytomcat\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4\tomcat-7.0.22\Uploaded Files\1146Wj.jpeg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="304" height="228" />
```

But always the result is as the alt value (That is Pulpit rock )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft:

```
file:///E|/liferaytomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4/tomcat-7.0.22/Uploaded Files/1146Wj.jpeg
```

But a website cannot access files on the local machine, unless that site is served *by* the local machine:

> Internet Explorer 6  Service Pack 1 (SP1) no longer allows browsing a local machine from the Internet zone. For instance, if an Internet site contains a link to a local file, Internet Explorer 6  SP1 displays a blank page when a user clicks on the link. Previous versions of Windows Internet Explorer followed the link to the local file.

Reference:

- [File protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Is the web-page being served from your machine?

Comment: Yes i am developing a site and it runs on localhost

Comment: Then I don't know what's happening (on my own machine, Win XP), the format `src="file:///C|\Documents and Settings\David\Desktop\drPooh.jpg"` works fine. Are you sure the image is where, and *what*, you think it is?

Comment: yes , i have cross checked twice and posted , anyway thanks fr the code . That code doesn''t suit as this should work on linux also

Comment: I am sorry i tried with jpg instead of jpeg , then its fine .Thanks David

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad to have been of, at least *some*, help. =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file:///e:/....
```

which is the required URL format for an absolute path on a windows system.

This assumes that the HTML file is also served from your file system, and not a remote webserver.

Comment: U mean src="file:///E:\liferaytomcat\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4\tomcat-7.0.22\Uploaded Files\1146Wj.jpeg" ?? thats not workig either